# How to move numbers from a file into an array in c++

Tags: c++, function, file-io

I am having trouble calling data from a file I have created, named 'numbers.txt'. The file has the numbers 1-26, which are supposed to be placed into an array. Right now it is not compiling. I have had similar projects with no issue. So I don't know what I am doing wrong. Below is the code I am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes:
int readEncodingCipher(string filename, int encodeKey[], int size);

int main()
{
    string fileName;
    const int size = 26;
    int encodeKey[size];

    //Requests the name of a file to read from.
    cout << "Please enter a file name with a key: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    readEncodingCipher(fileName, encodeKey, size);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int readEncodingCipher(string fileName, int encodeKey[], int size)
{
    string fileName;
    ifstream inFile;
    int num;
    int counter = 0;
    inFile.open(fileName);

    if (inFile)
    {
        while (inFile >> num && counter <= size)
        {
            encodeKey[counter] = num;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "unable to locate file";
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: If it isn't compiling you should include the full error message in your question.

Comment: In addition to the error log you should also upload the number file.

Comment: `counter <= size` ==> `counter < size`

Comment: Why an `int` return type when the function doesn't return anything?

Comment: Avoid repeating variable names. It mostly leads to pain.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you get the error message

```
error: declaration of 'std::__cxx11::string fileName' shadows a parameter
```

In you function

```
int readEncodingCipher(string fileName, int encodeKey[], int size)
{
    string fileName;
```

the local variable `fileName` shadows the parameter `filename`. You have to change the variable names. After fixing this error, it compiles for me.

In addition, you should fix the return type of the function. Either change it to `void` or return a value.

You should fix the counter of the while loop. The last element is `encodeKey[size - 1]`, so the while loop should stop at this element.